# How can I generate random numbers and assign them to variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I want the variables a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 to be random numbers from the uniform distribution U(0,100). I could write

```
import random

a_1 = random.uniform(0,100) 
a_2 = random.uniform(0,100) 
a_3 = random.uniform(0,100)
a_4 = random.uniform(0,100)
```

But I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. I tried the following,

```
import random

for i in range(4):
    a_i = random.uniform(1,100)
    print(a_i)
```

However, this did not work. For example, when I call a_1 later on, it says a_1 is not defined. How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do something in the second piece of code like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop

If you only need the 4 variables just stick with the first piece of code.

Comment: If it weren't for the XY problem going on here, this would be an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.cl/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the random values into a list and then access members by index:

```
>>> import random
>>> a = [random.uniform(1,100) for _ in range(4)]
>>> a
[71.4615087249735, 19.04308860149112, 40.278774122696014, 69.18947997939686]
>>> a[0]
71.4615087249735
>>> a[2]
40.278774122696014
```

Unless you have a really, really good reason, defining variables dynamically is kind of hard to justify.

Comment: @Brain Thanks a lot, I never thought of making a list. However, what is wrong with the code that I wrote, why did it not work?

Comment: @Artus because variables don't work dynamically like that.  Your code only defined one variable `a_i` which has no relation to the `i` being iterated in the loop.  Regardless of how many times you loop, you're still only reassigning to the one variable `a_i`.  What you want is a list (essentially an array) like @Brian's answer, so you can loop through the list like `a[i]`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to use a list, you can use the unpack functionality

```
import random
up, down, strange, charm = [random.uniform(1,100) for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: Rofl... Took me a while to catch that one ;-)

Comment: @Camion thank you but I'm not sure I understand what up down strange charm means...

Comment: Those are just example of names for if you want named variables instead of position in a structure (those name are colors of [quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark), just for fun).

Comment: The pack/unpack mechanism allows you to initialize multiple variables in one single operation : (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3), but in this case the outside parenthesis are not required : a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 1):

it seems You need numbers in range(0,100), well if you wanna generate **random integer** within a range(or other iterable)
try this.
**just in case you need it to be more specific**

`import random
 numberOf_intRequired=4
 random_int=random.sample(range(0,100),numberOf_intRequired)`